# Java loops how to make incremental with jump?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Trying to make a loop in java that goes like this

```
1
2
3
4
5
1000
1010
1020
1030
1040
```

Right now my code is

```
 for(int j = 1; j <=5; j += 1){
     for(int i = 1000; i <=1040; i += 10){
         System.out.println(+ j );
         System.out.println(+ i );
     }
 }
```

And this is not working at all as its printing every number 5 times.

Comment: You can just have two separate loops. Don't need to combine them.

Comment: Or you can do it in one loop ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Two separate loops since there is no relation between first 5 and last 5 numbers.

```
for(int j = 1; j <=5; j += 1) {
    System.out.println(j);
}

for(int i = 1000; i <=1040; i += 10){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.
If your purpose is to only display the number like above.
Then you can do that with one for statement.

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    for(int j = 1; j <=5; j += 1){
      System.out.println(j);
    }
    for(int i = 1000; i <=1040; i += 10){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you really really really want to do it in one loop:

```
int i=1;
while(i<=1040)
{
   System.out.println(i);
   if(i<5){i++; continue;}
   else if(i==5){i=1000; continue;}
   else i+=10; 
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
1000
1010
1020
1030
1040
```

Otherwise just use 2 for loops (the first with +1 increment, the second with +10 increments) in sequence and not nested.

```
for(int j=1; j<=5; j++) {
    System.out.println(j);
}

for(int j=1000; j<=1040; j+=10){
    System.out.println(j);
}
```